# Receiving 2 urls from gravity forms and putting them separately into 2 different columns

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, google-sheets-api

I am doing a small project where i will receive information from gravity forms plugin in wordpress and then parse that info into google sheets.
So far i am able to do that without a problem. The issue occurs when one of the fields which is a file upload field ( max files to be uploaded are 2 ) . The links are put together like this for example: "www.example.org/wp-content-uploads/gravityforms/image1.jpg","www.example.org/wp-content-uploads/gravityforms/image1.jpg"

What i would like it to do is 
!([http://imgur.com/a/BUXvn](https://imgur.com/a/BUXvn))!

Where it will display the full string in the doctor source column ( column 3) , and then split it into 2 using the comma as the delimiter and show it in doctor image1 and doctor image2.

Here is the code i have used to do the parsing in php.

```
add_action('gform_after_submission_1', 'add_to_google_spreadsheet', 10,        2);
function add_to_google_spreadsheet($entry, $form) {
// This is the web app URL of your Google Script create in previous step
$post_url =  'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwFTe3H0w8bp_2yviORAGhNZzIwvmKmdaCHf KEOdORwjO6pJPQ/exec';
// Put all the form fields (names and values) in this array
$doctor=('doctor source => rgar($entry,3)');
$doctorimage= explode(",",$doctor);
$body = array('first name' => rgar($entry, '1'), 'last name' =>  rgar($entry, '2'),'doctor source' => rgar($entry, '3'),'doctor image1' =>  rgar($doctorimage[0], '4'),'doctor image2' => rgar($doctorimage[1], '5'),);
// Send the data to Google Spreadsheet via HTTP POST request
$request = new WP_Http();
$response = $request->request($post_url, array('method' => 'POST',   'sslverify' => false, 'body' => $body));
}
```

rgar : gravity forms usage
Returns a value within an array
Usage
rgar( $array, $name );

For anyone looking to do the same , here is a guide I had used: https://ctrlq.org/code/20047-gravity-forms-to-google-spreadsheet

Comment: So - the issue (I think?) is that you can get the two URL's, but can't post them into separate columns? Is that true?

Comment: Yes indeed, i am receiving the 2 urls but they are in the same string and separated by a comma. Trying to get them into 2 different columns as you said.

Comment: What do you get when you `var_dump($body)` (after `$body` is set, but before it is sent).

Comment: @cale_b I get the following: `C:\wamp\www\test\wp-content\themes\twentysixteen\functions.php:432:
array (size=5)
  'first name' => string 'test' (length=4)
  'last name' => string 'teswt' (length=5)
  'doctor source' => string '["http:\/\/localhost\/test\/wp-content\/uploads\/gravity_forms\/1-8ff6b0fe8ef6a220af5effbd30f17ab0\/2016\/10\/20161017_1711134.jpg","http:\/\/localhost\/test\/wp-content\/uploads\/gravity_forms\/1-8ff6b0fe8ef6a220af5effbd30f17ab0\/2016\/10\/8d0b7b598bac76cdd893dff5c470abde4.jpg"]' (length=280)
  'doctor image1' => null
  'doctor image2' => null `

Comment: @cale_b So what i see is it doesnt even pass the value to the doctor image1 and 2 .

Comment: What is this line supposed to do?: `$doctor=('doctor source => rgar($entry,3)');`?

Comment: @cale_b  its doing nothing. did var dump for it and its just mistake from my side.  `C:\wamp\www\test\wp-content\themes\twentysixteen\functions.php:432:string 'doctor source => rgar($entry,3)' (length=31)`  So now the question is how to pass the string so that i can explode it and put it in 2 different columns i guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there's just some minor formatting / logic issues to sort out.

Here's my best attempt at this point, given the info you've provided.  There are some questions that may change the response:

```
// Adjust this line to simply GET the field for the doctor images
$doctor =rgar( $entry, 3 );
// Now, given the revision above, this line should properly explode the images
$doctorimage = explode( ',', $doctor );
// Adjust the below to put the images in (no need for rgar for them here)
$body = array(
    'first name'    => rgar( $entry, '1' ), 
    'last name'     => rgar( $entry, '2' ),
    'doctor source' => rgar( $entry, '3' ),
    'doctor image1' => $doctorimage[0],
    'doctor image2' => $doctorimage[1]
);
// Send the data to Google Spreadsheet via HTTP POST request
//....
```

Questions that may make a difference:
1. What IS field 3 in your form? Based on your code, it's the two urls for the images - is that right?
2. IS there a field 4 (and field 5) in your form? What do they contain?
3. What is the field in your form that is supposed to be the "doctor source"?

Comment: 1. Yes that is right. Its the 2 links in 1 line seperated with a comma.  </br/>                                                                                                    2. There is 4 and 5 , they contain email and contact number. <br/>     3. Its an upload field that lets users upload multiple images ( these are the images that give the 2 links mentioned in answer 1) .I hope i answered it properly. Once again , your solution was spot on. If you have any feedback once you read the answers to the question,please do let me know. You are amazing.

Comment: How do i put newline here. So i can format the above comments.

Comment: Unfortunately there's no way I know of to put newlines in comments!

Comment: Hey, quick follow up question , so when they files come in they are in this format ["http:\/\/localhost\/test\/wp-content\/uploads\/gravity_forms\/1-8ff6b0fe8ef6a220af5effbd30f17ab0\/2016\/10\/guide.png","http:\/\/localhost\/test\/wp-content\/uploads\/gravity_forms\/1-8ff6b0fe8ef6a220af5effbd30f17ab0\/2016\/10\/20161017_1711137.jpg"]          Are the extra backslash and [ ] due to it being on localhost? Is there anyway to remove them so that they become clickable links.

Comment: The backslashes are NOT due to localhost.  And yes, before you send them, wrap them in [stripslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php): `stripslashes( $doctorimage[0] );`